# Refund for mistaken credit card charge is less than initial charge, apparently due to exchange rates and/or fees

Tags: usa, payment-cards, exchange, refunds

A hotel wrongly charged my credit card (for mini-bar items I never took). I emailed them and they refunded me. Only they refunded me a smaller amount than the initial charge. I expect the difference comes from currency exchange fees and/or actual differences in exchange rates between the date the credit card was charged and the refund.

It seems strange to me that I end up losing money due to charges that I never consented to and they had no legitimate reason to make. (Even if the exchange rates could perhaps also have  worked in my favor, I never consented to making this gamble.) Do I have the right to get the full refund including these fees and/or changes in exchange rates?

(The hotel was in the US, the credit card used was French.)

Comment: Similar thing happened to me (except the wrong charge for me was the entire hotel stay that had already been pre-paid).  I had to wear the currency exchange difference as that had nothing to do with the hotel.  They refunded me the exact amount, in their currency, that they had mistakenly charged.  You could argue it with them if you like but I feel the only way you'll get what you want is if you get someone in a happy mood on the day.  I don't feel there's any obligation here

Comment: For a few months, USD ⇾ EUR rates have been [falling fast](https://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=USD&to=EUR), this is pretty sure this the issue here

Comment: Thanks. I actually also still have the recourse of contesting the charge with my bank. I think this might just undo the whole charge on my side meaning I get the full refund. Only now that option has also been made more complicated as it would probably require me refunding the refund (where some money will probably disappear again but this time on the hotels side).

Comment: You could try your bank but at least in my country they believe in taking money in rather than giving it out (except to their chief executives) so I would not hold your breath. I fear you just have to write it off as another cost of foreign travel.

Comment: Your statement should always show the amount in the original currency (USD) in the details of the transaction. Check that (it might be hidden in the description) and see if it is the same amount for both transactions. The applicable exchange rate might also be listed there.

Comment: Could any of you (who obviously have knowledge of what happened and why) PLEASE post an answer, instead of a comment?

Comment: What exactly has happened? Has the hotel itemised the charges and the refund? Do they make deductions explicit? Your bank may be reluctant to get involved if there has already been a partial refund, and if you do take it up with your bank you will need to be able to explain exactly what was paid and refunded, so you'll need to know this. ( You may have a case in law to sue the hotel for your entire loss, but that may not be easy.)

Comment: How much is the difference?

Comment: Not worth a separate answer, but *who made on the deal?* The currency exchange company. They made twice, in fact, once for each transaction. It's known as bid/offer spread, where the price to transact either way includes a little for them. I you change a dollar for € [or indeed any currency] then immediately change it back, you won't get a dollar.

Comment: This smells like an intentionally rip-off.

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/124824/32127

Comment: Interestingly, if you opt for getting charged in the card currency instead of in the local currency, this is not a risk and the refunded amount exactly matches the charged amount. NOTE: It is not recommended to opt for getting charged in the card currency, but this is an edge case where it would help.

Comment: @AriBrodsky : You're right.. updated my comment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Technically, you *could* argue that the hotel's actions have caused you to suffer a financial loss and you could sue them for compensation.  It would be a less than slam dunk case, because I'm sure their T&Cs disclaim responsibility for any indirect damages like this, and in practice, unless your minibar was stacked with gold bullion, resorting to the legal system is unlikely to be worth it.

If it's a major brand, you could drop a short, polite letter to customer service and they'll probably give you some points for your trouble.  If it's an independent operation, maybe you'll get a discount coupon for a future stay.

Anecdote time: back when dinosaurs roamed the earth, I bought some tickets from Jet Airways (India) for around $400, but turns out they had "upgraded" their systems the previous day and I was mistakenly charged over $14,000.  (I wasn't the only one either, and their issues made the news. This was also over my credit limit and I had another discussion with my bank about how *that* was possible.) Long story short, I was eventually refunded, but due to exchange rate changes got back about $150 less than I was supposed to. It took another round of complaints until they finally made me whole -- and proceeded to go bankrupt a few years later.

Comment: I doubt you could sue them for anything. They charged $X and refunded $X, you'll go to a US court to sue them and say what exactly?

Comment: @littleadv You can say that their actions resulted in consequential damages, namely the exchange rate loss: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequential_damages

Comment: You'll first need to prove their fault, which IMHO the OP has no way of doing. It's "he said she said", the hotel agreed to refund out of the goodness of their heart, but if they have a report from the floor attendant that a cookie was missing there's no way the OP can prove they took nothing from the minibar. So no, there's nothing to sue for.

Comment: @littleadv You can sue anybody for anything, it's for the court to decide who's wrong and who's right. We both agree the OP's case isn't particularly strong, but if they're paying up front and are willing to spend thousands to litigate over a few cents in exchange fees, I'm sure they can find a lawyer willing to take it up.

Answer (score 13):

The difference in rates - who does it go to?

The hotel charged in USD and refunded in USD - the hotel didn't gain anything. The credit card processor paid in USD and was refunded in USD - they didn't earn anything either.

Your own credit card issuer charged EUR and refunded EUR, and they charged more than they refunded, but did they gain anything? No, because they converted the USD charge to EUR and charged you what they had to pay, and similarly got a refund in USD and converted it to EUR to refund you back.

So who do you want to eat the difference? Clearly you don't want to be "it", but someone has to and you have the least power in this process. So it remains you. You can potentially talk to the hotel, but they have no reason to give you back more USD than you initially gave them. Your bank will most definitely not give you money they don't have to give to you.

As you said, it could have moved the opposite direction and then you'd be the one benefiting. You didn't *chose* to make this gamble, but that's how it works. It's one of the risks of using international credit cards.

I don't think contesting the charge with your bank will work, since you were refunded. You have no reason to contest. Unless the refund doesn't actually match the original charge in the original currency, of course.

Comment: In a case like this, generally the one to "be it" should be the one who made the mistake? OP also "had the least power" when they found the initial mistake, but the stronger parties nonetheless were pushed to fix it - likely due to mixes of desires to do right, for a positive image, and/or the theoretical danger of legal action. I'd think all those motivations remain. Though I agree when it's such a small amount, there tends to be much less motivation, and so OP may end up having to eat it. But certainly the hotel is the one who should. **Do I have the right** yes? Your answer sidesteps the Q

Comment: @JeopardyTempest what *should be* and what *is* are very different things. Who made the mistake? hard to tell. Maybe it was the OP who forgot that they actually took some cookie and the hotel decided to refund instead of arguing. Maybe it was the hotel maid who doesn't know how to count. Maybe the reception clerk who attributed the charge to the wrong room. We don't know. What **is** though is that the charge was reversed and the hotel paid back the exact amount they promised. The OP has no claim against the hotel, the exchange rate is not the hotel's problem.

Comment: "A hotel wrongly charged my credit card" makes it quite clear from the question that the fault is with the hotel (no one can know what reality is, or extend it to other situations, but as far as this question is written, we're given that information to start from...)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest "A hotel wrongly charged my credit card" should be read as "The hotel charged my credit card for incidentals as agreed, and I'm now claiming that the incidentals never happened". Which is different from the meaning you're attributing to that claim, and is more factually correct. We all have been charged "wrongly" one way or another by hotels and airlines, but in the end we all know that this is a disagreement and not a statement of fact.

Comment: _"the hotel didn't gain anything"_, they had the money, which would have collected interest or offered other investment opportunities.

Comment: The hotel maid, clerk, etc. are all agents of the hotel. As far as the customer is concerned, it's just one "hotel" entity. If the hotel chooses to dock (or worse) the pay of the employee with ultimate responsibility, that's their problem, but it shouldn't affect who the customer gets reimbursement from.

Comment: @Barmar the hotel can blame the customer, both of them can blame the banks, in the end it doesn't matter - T&C of the credit card and the hotel booking is what matters.

Comment: @littleadv In the OP the hotel admitted to the charging error.

Comment: @Barmar We don't actually know that, we only know that they refunded the full amount. Which is what they promised to do. It's not their fault that the OP is French. From the OP's initial statement (and from my experience in these situations), the hotel didn't actually admit any mistake.

Comment: @littleadv But they didn't blame the customer or the bank -- they took the action that suggests taking responsibility for the error.

Comment: @Barmar no, they took the action that suggest potential mitigation of a bad review.

Comment: Hmmm what's wrong with EU law? In US law I could cut my card and tell the bank if they want the money for that bad charge to bring a court case to which I will demand a jury.

Comment: @Joshua this makes no sense at all. How would that even work? The op is talking about a refund, not a charge

Comment: @littleadv: OP began with "A hotel wrongly charged my credit card" ; wrong charges are to be unwound not refunded.

Comment: @Joshua The OP *claims* they were wrongly charged, but were they? We don't know. It's the same as the claim from another commenter that "the hotel admitted their mistake" - they didn't admit their mistake, and the claim that they were wrongfully charged is OP's opinion only, not a statement of a fact. The hotel agreed to refund the charge and they did, what exactly cutting your credit card would achieve? That said, in the US just refusing paying a credit card bill will only land you in a ruined credit score situation and all the rest of your cards cancelled. No jury needed.

Comment: @littleadv Cutting the card makes no sense, but often the process of dealing with a fraudulent charge is to register the dispute with the credit card company/bank. They then contact the vendor to resolve it. This is one of the benefits of paying by credit card.

Comment: @Barmar for sure, but that only works if the merchant is not cooperating, which is not the case here.

Comment: @littleadv True, asking for a refund from the merchant is the first step