# Accidental bank transaction fees

Tags: bookings, money, hotels

The hotel in Munich I stayed in a few weeks ago, accidentally charged my Visa card twice, which led to an extra 1000 Euro charge to my account. My UK bank charges fees for the use of this card outside the UK, so I got an extra £25 in fees.
When I mentioned the mistake to the hotel, they reimbursed me the wrongly charged amount. However, they did not cover the fee and the exchange rate between Euro and Pound also changed in the meantime, which led to an additional £4 I did not get back.
They claim that they are not responsible for currency conversion or bank fees.
However, I never allowed them to use my card twice, so I feel like they have to cover the cost associated with their mistake. What can I do to enforce this?

Comment: Did you contact the bank about this?

Comment: Not yet... I was wondering whether I could ask the bank to undo the charge, but the bank customer service hotline takes ages, so I haven't gotten through yet... do you think that is the best way forward?

Comment: We've had a question about this before but I can't find it :/ Long story short, your bank is probably the best avenue to get this resolved.

Comment: It’s _possible_ that the bank will actually cancel the fee automatically but that it just takes longer. If not you can try to ask the bank, though it depends a lot on their terms. Otherwise you can try the local equivalent of small claims court in the merchant’s country, but this is going to be a hassle and will probably end up costing you more than the fees.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Similar/related:  https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178781/4171

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refund for mistaken credit card charge is less than initial charge, apparently due to exchange rates and/or fees](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178781/refund-for-mistaken-credit-card-charge-is-less-than-initial-charge-apparently-d)

Answer (score 7):

Ok talking to my bank, they were willing to reimburse the fee. However, the shortfall of the currency conversion cannot be resolved by my bank. I still think the hotel is at fault and should cover the entire cost, but it might not be worth the effort.

Comment: What the hotel *should* have done was reverse the transaction, which "unwinds" everything associated with the transaction and in theory leaves you back in the same position you were in before. What they probably did instead was to pay you €1000 - the end result being 3 transactions (2 debits & one credit) on your account instead of one.

Comment: yes that is correct... I agree if they could have reversed their incorrect transac tion, that would have solved the issue imidiately

Comment: can you request a chargeback on the original transaction?

Comment: @njzk2 that could be considered fraudulent at this point as they have already admitted their mistake and refunded the amount charged.